# XCode snippet with automatically generated date and correct tabs

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets

I've got a question regarding code snippets in XCode. I'm using them a lot, but there are 2 things that bother me since using them:

- How can I add a placeholder for an automatically generated date? Is this possible, or do I have to write a script that inserts the date when the snippet is created...?
- How can I format tab spaces in a code snippet so that the inserted code actually contains tabs and not only spaces?

Would be great if someone of you out there could answer these questions, because I think these things should be possible without much effort.

Have a nice day!
chris

Comment: tab spaces?dont get it